# HTML tags into ERB form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, erb

Just to add to previous question, what if you wanted to add HTML into an ERB tag

I tried to do this:

```
<%=button_to "<i class="fa fa-usd"></i>#{@current_user.profile.current_balance}0".html_safe, withdraw_url, :id=>"wallet_link", :class=>"btn btn-default", :method => :get %>
```

But that obviously gave an error. How would you add HTML tags into that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`button_to ... do`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-button_to), like this:

```
<%= button_to withdraw_url, :id => "wallet_link", :class => "btn btn-default", :method => :get do %>
  <i class="fa fa-usd"></i><%= @current_user.profile.current_balance %>0
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<%=button_to "<i class='fa fa-usd'></i>#{@current_user.profile.current_balance}0".html_safe, withdraw_url, :id=>"wallet_link", :class=>"btn btn-default", :method => :get %>
```

You can't simply put double quotes inside double-quoted string. You should escape them with backslash or use single quotes

Comment: That works from an ERB perspective, but does not get the HTML interpret. So you end up with getting <<i class='fa fa-usd'></i displayed in the button

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you:

```
<%= button_to "<i class='fa fa-usd'></i>#{@current_user.profile.current_balance}0".html_safe, withdraw_url, :id=>"wallet_link", :class=>"btn btn-default", :method => :get %>
```

Comment: That works from an ERB perspective, but does not get the HTML interpret. So you end up with getting <<i class='fa fa-usd'></i displayed in the button.